# cakephp find('list') for select box

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to implement selectbox in my site.Option for that selectbox is set in my controller like below

```
$tmp_user = $this->User->find('first',array('id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')));
                $zip_info = $this->Zipcode->find('first',array('id'=>@$tmp_user['User']['zip_id']));
                $region_admins = $this->AdminRegion->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('AdminRegion.region_id'=>@$zip_info['Zipcode']['region_id'])));

if(!empty($region_admins)){         
                    foreach($region_admins as $radmn):
                        //pr($radmn);
                        $admin_user = $this->User->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$radmn['AdminRegion']['user_id']),'fields'=>array('id','username')));                
                        pr($admin_user);
                        $this->set('users',$admin_user);
                    endforeach;
```

I am getting value like this when i print from controller

```
Array
(
    [137] => governmentuser1
)
Array
(
    [198] => testadmin
)
Array
(
    [215] => adminregion
)
Array
(
    [224] => testcompany1234
)
Array
(
    [225] => testuser12345678
)
```

but only last value is set in select box....
Where did i made mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<?php
    $tmp_user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                    'id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
                ));

    $zip_info = $this->Zipcode->find('first', array(
                    'id' => @$tmp_user['User']['zip_id']
                ));
    $region_admins = $this->AdminRegion->find('list', array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'AdminRegion.region_id' => @$zip_info['Zipcode']['region_id']
                        ),
                        'fields' => array('AdminRegion.user_id', 'AdminRegion.user_id')
                     ));

    $admin_users = $this->User->find('list', array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'id' => $region_admins
                        ),
                        'fields' => array(
                            'id','username'
                        )
                    ));

    ?>
```

A few side notes:

- Why do another query for the user data? Isn't it all in the session?
- I wouldn't use the @ anywhere, it's slower and suppresses errors. It will make debugging a nightmare too.

Comment: I agree with this approach. I think your problem above is that you're querying for the `list` of `$admin_users` from *inside* the `foreach` loop. That's why you get multiple arrays instead of one array with the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed array:

```
$admin_user[] = $this->User->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$radmn['AdminRegion']['user_id']),'fields'=>array('id','username')));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes, it works but it gives me a complex array which results me option group in selectbox  eg:first entry is under option group...I want to escape from that.