# php array traverse

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

My result in php returns following array.

```
Array (
    [137] => governmentuser1 
) 
Array (
    [198] => testadmin
)
Array (
    [215] => adminregion
)
Array (
    [224] => testcompany1234 
) 
Array (
    [225] => testuser12345678 
)
```

how can i convert it to this form to set option value in cakephp selectbox

```
Array (
    [137] => governmentuser1
    [198] => testadmin
    [215] => adminregion
    [224] => testcompany1234
    [225] => testuser12345678

)
```

Comment: Where do you get this from? If you're using Cake, it seems like you're doing something wrong to get this kind of array...

Comment: jafar asked this in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276995). I think the unusual format is due to how that part of jafar's app is coded and should probably be addressed there, instead of combining these results afterward.

Answer (score 5):

It's as easy as this:

```
$total = $result1 + $result2 + $result3 + ...
```

What you call "your result" is actually not one single array - you have 5 different arrays there. To preserve the keys you need to merge them using the + (plus) operator instead of using `array_merge`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_merge()` function to help you merge all the arrays together.

Comment: Beware that `If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator`

Comment: Looks like his keys are the IDs of records in his database so it wouldn't matter if he overwrote elements with matching keys or not (as they would contain the same values).